# Terrible performance on WP-generated query migrating from MySQL to MariaDB

Tags: mysql, performance, index, mariadb, explain

I'm trying to migrate a website from a WP-focused hosting provider that uses Percona for their DB node to a Jelastic-based provider that offers MariaDB for its DB nodes.

There's one query in particular (though not the only one) that runs significantly slower.

```sql
explain SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.*
FROM   wp_posts
       INNER JOIN wp_postmeta
               ON ( wp_posts.id = wp_postmeta.post_id )
       INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1
               ON ( wp_posts.id = mt1.post_id )
WHERE  1 = 1
       AND ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_llms_order'
             AND (( mt1.meta_key = '_llms_parent_section'
                    AND mt1.meta_value =247476 )) )
       AND (( wp_posts.post_type = 'lesson'
              AND ( wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
                     OR wp_posts.post_status = 'expired'
                     OR wp_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled'
                     OR wp_posts.post_status = 'llms-completed'
                     OR wp_posts.post_status = 'llms-active'
                     OR wp_posts.post_status = 'llms-expired'
                     OR wp_posts.post_status = 'llms-on-hold'
                     OR wp_posts.post_status = 'llms-pending-cancel'
                     OR wp_posts.post_status = 'llms-pending'
                     OR wp_posts.post_status = 'llms-cancelled'
                     OR wp_posts.post_status = 'llms-refunded'
                     OR wp_posts.post_status = 'llms-failed'
                     OR wp_posts.post_status = 'llms-txn-failed'
                     OR wp_posts.post_status = 'llms-txn-pending'
                     OR wp_posts.post_status = 'llms-txn-refunded'
                     OR wp_posts.post_status = 'llms-txn-succeeded'
                     OR wp_posts.post_status = 'tribe-ea-success'
                     OR wp_posts.post_status = 'tribe-ea-failed'
                     OR wp_posts.post_status = 'tribe-ea-schedule'
                     OR wp_posts.post_status = 'tribe-ea-pending'
                     OR wp_posts.post_status = 'tribe-ea-draft'
                     OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private' ) ))
GROUP  BY wp_posts.id
ORDER  BY wp_postmeta.meta_value + 0 ASC
LIMIT  0, 999999
```

This query is generated by WordPress. It gets all lessons within a specific section, ordering them by another postmeta value.

On Percona, it runs in 0.05 seconds. On Maria, it runs in 1.5 seconds (!!!).

MariaDB EXPLAIN results:

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra | FIELD11 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | wp_posts | ref | PRIMARY | type_status_date | type_status_date | 82 | const | 31655 | Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
| 1 | SIMPLE | mt1 | ref | post_id | meta_key | post_id | 8 | dbname.wp_posts.ID | 15 | Using where |
| 1 | SIMPLE | wp_postmeta | ref | post_id | meta_key | post_id | 8 | dbname.wp_posts.ID | 15 | Using where |

Mysql EXPLAIN results:

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra | FIELD13 | FIELD14 | FIELD15 | FIELD16 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | mt1 | NULL | ref | post_id | meta_key | meta_key | 767 | const | 33378 | 10.00 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |  |  |  |
| 1 | SIMPLE | wp_posts | NULL | eq_ref | PRIMARY | type_status_date | post_parent | post_author | post_name | PRIMARY | 8 | dbname.mt1.post_id | 1 | 26.35 | Using where |
| 1 | SIMPLE | wp_postmeta | NULL | ref | post_id | meta_key | post_id | 8 | dbname.mt1.post_id | 23 | 1.95 | Using where |  |  |  |

The postmeta table is indexed on post_id and meta_key.
The posts table has a multi-column index on post_type, post_status, post_date and ID.

I don't think the OS (or DB optimization values!) have any bearing whatsoever here. I've tested the same with MariaDB on the old host, MySQL on the new one, even local installations of both. There's on average an order of magnitude of difference between the two.

Am I running into a strange edge case? Is the strange index key chosen by MariaDB at fault?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Please edit your question and remove the images for the reasons outlined in [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/470530). Put in **formatted** text in their place!

Comment: Your question is not about a query [but this can give you some ideas](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: What versions of Percona/MySQL/MariaDB?  Is the MySQL Explain really on Percona?

Answer (score 2):

A kind sir from MariaDB's community slack helped me:

```
ANALYZE TABLE tbl PERSISTENT FOR ALL;
```

'Fixes' the table.

Answer (score 1):

Start by installing [*WP Index Improvements*](https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/)

If you still have problems, please provide the current results of `SHOW CREATE TABLE wp_posts` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE wp_postmeta`.  And fresh `EXPLAINs`.

The inability to directly use numeric values (cf `ORDER  BY wp_postmeta.meta_value + 0`) is an intrinsic deficiency in WP.